# Как добавить БД firebase в android studio?

Tags: android-studio, firebase-database

возникла проблема с добавлением базы данных в android studio, а именно не понимаю куда вписывать данный код:

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
   google()
}
 dependencies {
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
 }
}
allprojects {
 repositories {
   google()
 }
}
```

я знаю что код нужно вписать в build.gradle(project:), но я смотрел видео и статьи и у них данный файл выглядит по другому от чего я и не понимаю куда вставлять код, может у меня какие-то плагины не установлены или вроде того? Прошу помогите понять свою ошибку.

вот как выглядит у меня данный файл: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBxHr.png]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, спасибо за замечание как я понял вы говорите про текст на скриншоте верно ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение очень простое, ты просто открыл не тот build.gradle. Слева, там где файлы есть build.gradle(Project:BD) и build.gradle(Module:BD). Ты должен открыть второй файл тот что ниже build.gradle(Module:BD)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но лично я так не подключаю проект к Firebase потому что есть способ в разы легче. Нажимаешь на верхней панели Tools>Firebase и там выбираешь Realtime database или что то другое и подключаешь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]